# Changing link_to_route to auto route in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to change link_to_route to auto route
below are the code for my link_to_route for `views.php`:

```
{{link_to_route('frontend.logouthome', trans('Logout'))}}
```

My route.php:

```
Route::get('logouthome', 'auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logouthome');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if that is the I think, I think that you can create your own route like "logouthome" and you only need to call it from the view with `route()` or `url()` like: `{{ url('logouthome') }}` and from your route file `Route::get('logouthome', 'yourController@yourMethod');`